# Send an image from java client to python server

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send an image in the form of a byte array from a client application to a server. The server code is written in python while the client is written in java. The image is being transferred correctly however the image saved on the server machine is corrupted.

The following is the code for the server.

```
import socket
import struct

HOST = "192.168.1.100"
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

print('SERVER STARTED RUNNING')

while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    buf = ''
    while len(buf) < 4:
        buf += client.recv(4 - len(buf))
    size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)[0]
    with open('/home/isaac/Desktop/image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        while size > 0:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            f.write(data)
            size -= len(data)
    print('Image Saved')
    client.sendall('Image Received')
    client.close()
```

The following is the source code for the java client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] array = extractBytes("/home/isaac/Desktop/cat.jpg");
    Socket sock = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT_NO);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Array Length - " + array.length);
    dos.writeInt(array.length);
    dos.write(array);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```

Hopefully you can help me. I've tried to google to get my answer but no solution has worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what sense you get a corrupted image? I've tried it with the following array:

```
byte[] array = new byte[3000];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (byte)('0' + (i % 10));
}
```

and I get the same array I sent.

Another thing, just to be sure: the file is less than 2Gb, right?

Comment: The file is only 227.2 kB. When I open the image with an image view its giving me the following error: Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x33 0x44). Another thing, when I opened the original image and the transferred image using a text editor, the binary data was not the same.

Comment: might the problem be with your extractBytes function? Could you post the code of it?

Comment: The problem was with the extractBytes function. I used a file input stream and a byte array output stream which solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
File file = new File("picture path");
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```